# How do I decompress a json response that was compressed with gzip?

Tags: json, delphi, rest, encryption

I'm new to the Rest components in Delphi XE5. When I try to do a Rest request with the Rest components I get the data back but it's encrypted with gzip.  When I do a get with an idHTTP component I get the same, but this is resolved by assigning an IdCompressorZLib component to the idHTTP component. Now the response is readable and everything.  So I bypassed the Rest components and used the idHTTP component instead.

Now I'm trying to do a post. Because I did not really know how to make a post I reverted to the Rest components again.  The post worked, but again the response coming back is encrypted.  How do I decrypt this message?

Otherwise it would be awesome if I could get a post example using the idHTTP component instead.  I'm trying to post a json string to the server...

Any help would be highly appreciated 
Thanx

Comment: Is it really Encrypted, or merely compressed?

Comment: @ChrisThornton since gzip does not support encryption we also have to ask whether it is even gzip.  Either it is compressed with gzip or encrypted with something else... it cannot be *"encrypted with gzip"*.  However, since it is normal for a REST response to be zlib compressed with a gzip header, we can probably guess that's what OP meant, particularly since he seems to have had success using `IdCompressorZLib`.

Comment: @J... yeah, I meant it as kind of a probing question, to prompt the OP to re-examine his situation.

Comment: @ChrisThornton Yes, I felt the socratic thing going on there... sometimes I suppose I'm too much of a realist to put too much faith in it.  Was just helping OP along the re-examination journey.

Comment: The quality of NEW libraries from Embarcadero is not brilliant. You can wait few years before most bug would be fixed, of course. But maybe just use time-proven libraries like mormot? http://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests/

Comment: Perhaps easiest solution is to tell server that you don't support gzip, via an empty `Accept-Encoding:` header.

Comment: @MarcusAdams is it allwoed empty? perhaps it should be 'identity'

Comment: @Arioch'The, I'm going by the specs (blank = identity only), but perhaps specifying identity is better.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question just now. I cannot turn off the gzip...Any idea how to go about decompressing the response with the built in REST Components?

Comment: @ChrisThornton, it is compressed, that is what I meant...